# separating html in spa

Tags: jquery, html, single-page-application

I have started to create a simple single page application using HTML and jQuery. My problem is that all the code is in the index file and is quickly going to become unmanageable:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SPA</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<!-- Page 1 -->
        <section id="page-1">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
            <p>This is page 1</p>
            <a href="#" class="page-2-btn">Go to page 2</a>
            <a href="#" class="page-3-btn">Go to page 3</a>
        </section>

<!-- Page 2 -->
        <section id="page-2" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
            <p>This is page 2</p>
            <a href="#" class="page-1-btn">Go to page 1</a>
            <a href="#" class="page-3-btn">Go to page 3</a>
        </section>

<!-- Page 3 -->
        <section id="page-3" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Page 3</h1>
            <p>This is page 3</p>
            <a href="#" class="page-1-btn">Go to page 1</a>
            <a href="#" class="page-2-btn">Go to page 2</a>
        </section>

<!-- jQuery navigation code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var animationSpeed = 500;
        var currentPage = "#page-1";

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".page-1-btn").click(function() {
                $(currentPage).fadeOut(animationSpeed, function(){
                    $("#page-1").fadeIn(animationSpeed);
                    currentPage = "#page-1";
                });
            });

            $(".page-2-btn").click(function() {
                $(currentPage).fadeOut(animationSpeed, function(){
                    $("#page-2").fadeIn(animationSpeed);
                    currentPage = "#page-2";
                });
            });

            $(".page-3-btn").click(function() {
                $(currentPage).fadeOut(animationSpeed, function(){
                    $("#page-3").fadeIn(animationSpeed);
                    currentPage = "#page-3";
                });
            });

        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way of separating the pages out so that the code is more modular?

I am considering converting it to a javascript MVC framework which would allow me to separate the html into views but since the pages are basically static and I am only using an spa so that the navigation is smooth I am not sure it is worth the extra time. I also do not want the app to keep a history which most mvc frameworks seem to have as standard.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the html in separate `pageX.html` files and use `jQuery.load()` to load them into the main page. Javascript can also go in these html files since it will be executed on loading. From the point of the user it would still be a single page application.
See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more information.

Comment: This works great Raidri, thanks. Now I'd like to separate out the jQuery code - any suggestions for that?

Comment: Scripts in the separate page files (including jQuery) are executed on loading. So you can just put them in these files. Or you create one `pageX.js` file to every html file and load it with [`jQuery.get() (dataType: 'script')`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) for templates and [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/)